# VS Code HTML formatting wrong

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, formatting

I have a HTML file where the formatting is completely messed up. Hopefully you can the the problem in this picture below:

[image]

This is just an example from the file (other parts are messed up too). You can see that the `<table>` start tag and end tag don't have the same indentation. Also, I would expect everything inside the tag to be indented farther. This is how it looks after using the `Shift + Alt + F` code formatting shortcut. What could the problem be and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! I opened a issue in vscode's github https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74139#issuecomment-495578264. The older versions used to work I just got it solved rolling back to the version 1.17...